# App running on android studio emulator but not on real device :(

Tags: android, firebase, emulation

I am new to android and I was making an app using firebase authentication to let a user create an account and sign in. While making the app, I set the minimum android version to Marshmallow. Every thing works well when I run the code on the emulator.

I have made a variable name `isAdmin` and a `EditText` which is secret code, so when a user creates an account, if the user knows the secret code, he or she will get admin rights, else no admin rights will be given.

The problem is that when I run the app on the emulator it works fine, when I run using USB debugging in my phone it works fine, but when I generate an apk in Android Studio and install that app on my mobile and then I create an account, the app crashes without showing any error and when I look into my firebase database, all details like `first name`, `last name` exist in database but the variable `isAdmin` does not exist in the database.

I don't know why this variable is not getting stored in the database.
My phone is Marshmallow xiomi redmi 3s

Comment: Please add the code that you using and the database structure.

Comment: Maybe you have enabled minification/Proguard for your release builds and this is messing up your code. Have a look at your build configuration for `minifyEnabled true` and try setting it `false`. If this solves this issue you have to configure proguard correctly.